# Validating login and password on hover

Tags: javascript, html

MY HTML

```
<p id="login" onmouseover="showForm();" onmouseout="hideForm();"><span class="label">Login / Register</span>
              <span id="loginForm">        
                  <span class="form-elements">
                  <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
                  <span class="form-field">
                  <input type="text" id= "login1" onsubmit= "showform()"/>
                  </span> </span>        
                  <span class="form-elements">
                  <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
                  <span class="form-field">
                  <input type="password" id= "password1" onsubmit= "showform()"/>
                  </span> </span>        
                  <span class="form-elements">
                  <span class="submit-btn">
                  <input type="submit" value=" Submit " /></span> 
                  <a href="register.html"><button type="button" class="swd-button">Register</button></a>
                </span>
                </span></p>
```

My javascript

```
function showForm(){
    document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "block";
}

function hideForm(){
    document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "none";
}
```

My validation check

```
    var isValid = true;
                var login1 = document.getElementById('login1').value;
var password1 = document.getElementById('password1').value;
                if(login1 == null ||login1 == "")
                {   
                    document.getElementById("errorusername").innerHTML="[Please type something!]";
                    isValid = false;
                }

                if(password1 == null || password1 == "")
                {   
                    document.getElementById("errorpassword").innerHTML="[Please type something!]";  
                    isValid = false;

                }
                return isValid;
```

what im trying to do is validating the login and password. which is user cant put null only. anything else is acceptable. but then my showform is already a function. so where do i put my validation. well i tried putting it inside the `showform()` it doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code, but you have some things you need to address.

```
function validate(){
    document.getElementById('failed').innerHTML = "";
    var isValid = true;
    var login1 = document.getElementById('login1').value;
    var password1 = document.getElementById('password1').value;
    if(login1 == null ||login1 == "")
    {   
        document.getElementById('login1').value="Type Something";
        isValid = false;
    };

    if(password1 == null || password1 == "")
    {   
        document.getElementById('failed').innerHTML = "NEED A PASSWORD!";  
        isValid = false;
    };
};
```

I changed your HTML a bit too...

```
<p id="login"><span class="label">Login / Register</span>
<span id="loginForm">        
<span class="form-elements">
<span class="form-label">Name:</span>
<span class="form-field">
<input type="text" id= "login1" onsubmit= "showform()"/>
</span> </span>        
<span class="form-elements">
<span class="form-label">Password:</span>
<span class="form-field">
<input type="password" id= "password1" onsubmit= "showform()"/>
</span> </span>        
<span class="form-elements">
<span class="submit-btn">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" /></span> 
<a href="register.html"><button type="button" class="swd-button">Register</button></a>
</span>
</span><span id='failed' style="color:red;"></span></p>
```

You can't set the password field to "Type Something" because it will just show up as asterisks since password fields are hidden. So you need some type of outside element to notify the user that a password is required. That is why i added the span tag at the end.

If i was you, I would add both notifications for missing text in the fields outside of the boxes themselves... but that might be my preference.

One more thing... I don't know why you are using the span tags instead of a table... it makes it really hard to read...

Comment: thanks really appreciate it. finally understand what i did wrongly. btw i was using span because i have align it properly with my css. i tried the table but it ruin my alignment.